# What is the meaning in C when a function is in another function's name (not in the arguments)?

Tags: c, function-pointers, definition

Why is
"void   (*parse(char *op))(int, int)"
written like this? (main added to give use case), it gets called from a pointer "fun" with argv[2] without the ints (line 18)... and then again as "fun" with the ints (line 21)?

```
void    (*parse(char *op))(int, int)
{
    if (!strcmp(op, "+"))
        return(other stuff...); 
    else
        return (0);
}
int     main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int a;
    int b;
    void    (*fun)(int, int);

    if (argc == 4){
        a = atoi(argv[1]);
        fun = parse(argv[2]);
        b = atoi(argv[3]);
        if (fun)
            fun(a, b);
        else
            return(0);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

How does it technically work, and it is just a showoff with a simpler way to write it or is this the only correct grammar?

Comment: Welcome to the delights of pointers to functions.  `parse()` is a function returning a pointer to a function.  It would be interesting/helpful to know what the `other stuff...` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse()` is a function that returns a function pointer. You can use `typedef` with the type of the returned function to make it look a lot nicer, though:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// parser_func describes a function that takes two ints and returns nothing
typedef void (*parser_func)(int, int);

// Like this one.
void somefunc(int a, int b) {}

// And parse() is a function that takes a char* and returns a
// pointer to a function that matches parser_func.
parser_func parse(char *op) {
  if (!strcmp(op, "+"))
    return somefunc;
  else
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a;
  int b;
  parser_func fun; // Function pointer

  if (argc == 4) {
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    fun = parse(argv[2]); // Assign a function to fun
    b = atoi(argv[3]);
    if (fun) {
      fun(a, b); // And call it if it's not null
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is `void (*parse(char *op))(int, int)` written like this?

Because that is the syntax for returning a pointer to function. The return type is `void (*)(int, int)` which is a pointer to function that returns `void` and accepts two `int` arguments.

Usually, type aliases are used to make pointers to functions more readable:

```
typedef void operation(int, int);
using operation = void (int, int); // equivalent C++ alternative

operation* parse(char *op);
```

Comment: I suspect a better typedef name would be something like `operator` (except that the question is also tagged with C++) — maybe `calculator`, or use some upper-case (`Operator` or `Calculator`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Let's say `operation`